# UI Debugging Tools for XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I using Visual Studio 2015 Pro, I coding WPF XAML, but UI Debugging Tools for XAML doesn't work
I was enable `Tools->Options->Debugging->General->Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML, Preview selected elements in Live Visual Tree`
But it's still not work. Does anyone know to fix it?

Comment: Sometimes this happens to me when I use Snoop, run as administrator solved that issue. But, I am not sure about your's but give it a try.

Comment: @Davy I tried it but still not work :)

Answer (score 1):

it seems visual 2015 pro does not support UI Debugging Tools for XAML. I have tried install visual 2015 enterprise and finally it worked.